# I don't understand how to use modprobe --dump-modversions <filename>

Tags: linux, module

I'm just playing with modprobe and want to inspect the versioning information on a module called `soundcore`.

```bash
$ lsmod | grep soundcore
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

the kernel object resides in

```
$ find  /lib/modules/`uname -r`/ -name soundcore.ko.zst
/lib/modules/6.4.7-arch1-1/kernel/sound/soundcore.ko.zst
```

When I'm trying to `modprobe --dump-modversions /lib/modules/6.4.7-arch1-1/kernel/sound/soundcore.ko.zst`, I get an error complaining the file was not found, namely

```
modprobe: FATAL: could not get modversions of /lib/modules/6.4.7-arch1-1/kernel/sound/soundcore.ko.zst: No such file or directory
```

then tried `modprobe --dump-versions soundcore`, still no success. Then tired `sudo zstd -d <path_to_ko.zst> && modprobe --dump-modversions <path_to_ko>`, same error.

In the man page for `--dump-modversions`

> --dump-modversions
> Print out a list of module versioning information required by
> a module. This option is commonly used by distributions in
> order to package up a Linux kernel module using module
> versioning deps.

it's not clear what I need to do in this context. What kind of file do I need?